# WebSphere MQ 7, can I use one machine to send message to remote queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm new to WebSphere MQ. I was practicing the tutorials on the IBM site, I want to know if I need two separate computer machines to send a message to a remote queue? 
I'm using a laptop, I was wondering if I create another user account, can I use that user account to send message to a remote queue?

Answer (score 4):

A remote queue in WebSphere MQ terms is simply a queue that exists on another queue manager.  You do not need another server, nor even another account.  Just define two queue managers on the same server, under the same account and connect them.

```
crtmqm QMGR1
strmqm QMGR1

crtmqm QMGR2
strmqm QMGR2

runmqsc QMGR1
DEFINE LISTENER(TCP.1414) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1414) CONTROL(QMGR)
START LISTENER(TCP.1414)

DEFINE QL(QMGR2) USAGE(XMITQ) TRIGGER
DEFINE CHL(QMGR1.QMGR2) CHLTYPE(SDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) + 
       CONNAME('127.0.0.1(1415)') XMITQ(QMGR2) REPLACE
* Next one not needed for the demo but usually there's
* a channel for reply messages to return on.
DEFINE CHL(QMGR2.QMGR1) CHLTYPE(RCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) REPLACE

START CHL(QMGR1.QMGR2) 

DEFINE QREMOTE(TARGET.QUEUE) RQMNAME(QMGR2) RNAME(TARGET.QUEUE)
END


runmqsc QMGR2
DEFINE LISTENER(TCP.1415) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1415) CONTROL(QMGR)
START LISTENER(TCP.1415)

DEFINE QL(QMGR1) USAGE(XMITQ) TRIGGER
DEFINE CHL(QMGR2.QMGR1) CHLTYPE(SDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) + 
       CONNAME('127.0.0.1(1414)') XMITQ(QMGR1) REPLACE
DEFINE CHL(QMGR1.QMGR2) CHLTYPE(RCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) REPLACE

DEFINE QL(TARGET.QUEUE)
END
```

You can have as many QMgrs on one machine as resources allow.  I have seem people with as many as 20 QMgrs on a server but one is the recommended number.

If you have WMQ v7.0 or earlier you can have only one installation of WMQ on a machine.  If you have v7.1, which is current as of this writing, then it is possible to have multiple installations on the same machine.  But either way, all QMgrs on that machine run under the `mqm` account (or on Windows, whatever account you installed and run WMQ under).

Comment: You can run multiple WMQ 7.0 qmgrs under Windows and z/OS. I used to do it all the time in a prior ISV job.

Comment: Was my post confusing? You can have one installation of WMQ and many QMgrs defined under that installation with v7.0 and earlier. As of v7.1 you can have multiple installations of WMQ and, as before many QMgrs. Let me know what part of that was unclear and I'll clarify the post.

Comment: I found "If you have WMQ v7.0 or earlier you can have only one installation of WMQ on a machine" confusing, but I now realize it was very late when I read your comment and I probably confused with it with qmgrs versus installation. So it's probably good, but you might want to add that z/OS is an exception.

You can run multiple WMQ versions simultaneously in z/OS, and there are (sneaky) ways to get the different versions of ERLY to run at IPL. BTDTTS. :)

Comment: I think you just did!  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Nice example and explanation. I think there is a type, second runmqsc command is for QMGR2.

Comment: Very late reply but I have updated T.Rob's excellent post to fix the typo you pointed out 6 years ago :).